# How to style an inner table with boxable?

Tags: java, pdf, boxable

How can you change styles like border width, border color, text alignment, etc. of an inner table created with [boxable](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable)?

`SampleTest10` in the unit tests [here](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/blob/master/src/test/java/be/quodlibet/boxable/TableTest.java) creates an inner table by using HTML. The resulting table has default styles. How can you access and change them?

Comment: Which styles are you interested in ?

Comment: Border color, border width, background color of cells, text size and color

Comment: @thesys have you figured it out? Is there any way to style inner table?

Comment: Nope there isn't, I switched to Apache PDFBox eventually.

Answer (score 0):

### Table Class

I had a look at the boxable class for Table. It looks as if these are the only styling options you have ( atleast according to this class ) :

```
public Table(float yStartNewPage, float pageTopMargin, float pageBottomMargin, float width, float margin,
            PDDocument document, boolean drawLines, boolean drawContent, PageProvider<T> pageProvider)
```

See: https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/blob/master/src/main/java/be/quodlibet/boxable/Table.java

I see though that also HTML can be included, so maybe you should try using html formatting such as: e.g.  `<table bordercolor=”red”>`

### Cell Class

Cell class seems to have a LineStyle .
So it would make sense that in the following code (taken from unit test), you would be able to do additional actions.

```
Cell<PDPage> cell = headerRow.createCell(100, "Awesome Facts About Belgium");
        cell.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD);
        cell.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
        cell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

`cell.setBottomBorderStyle(new LineStyle(Color.RED, 2));`

```
        table.addHeaderRow(headerRow);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, an inner table is a `TableCell`, not an `Table`. So the styling options of `TableCell` are not the same as `Table`. I also tried to use HTML styling like `style="..."` and `bordercolor` but it does not work.

Comment: @Thesys, I noticed that Cell seems to have a LineStyle . https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/blob/master/src/main/java/be/quodlibet/boxable/Cell.java

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I am talking about an *inner* table. An inner table is a table which is *inside* a cell. Changing the style of the cell does not affect the table which is inside the cell.

Comment: An inner table is constructed like this (taken from SampleTest10)): `Cell<PDPage> cell3 = row2.createTableCell((100 / 3f),
    "<table><tr><td>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello it's me</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 </td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr><tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td></tr></table>",
doc, page, yStart, pageBottomMargin, margin);` Notice `createTableCell` != `createCell`

Comment: @Bobface How can I style(background or color) to a <td>?